# sed behavior: Pattern space and Address range

Tags: linux, sed

```
seq 1 5 | sed -n '1,2 d; 1,2 p;'
3
```

This is unexpected. Why 3?

```
seq 1 5 | sed -n '2 d; 2 p;'
seq 1 5 | sed -n '/1/,/2/ d; /1/,/2/ p;'
```

No output. This is expected.

Comment: See https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8762; but was fixed in GNU sed 4.3.

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine in GNU sed 4.4.